# Using dhcpcd to assign a static IP address on Debian

Tags: dhcpcd

I'm wanting to assign a static IP address to a Debian Stretch installed on a local network server.

Previously I was using `/etc/network/interfaces` to do it, the server has only one nic and my network has two routers, the server is mainly plugged into the second router with subnet 192.168.1.0, this router is not the one supplied by my ISP.  On the off chance that I need to connect the server to my ISP's router with subnet 192.160.0.1, I was wanting to configure the server with a static IP on each subnet as follows:

ISP Router: `192.168.0.250`

2nd Router: `192.168.1.250`

To assign a static IP on each subnet I configured `dhcpcd.conf` as follows.

```
interface enp30s0
arping 192.168.0.1
arping 192.168.1.1

# Static IP configuration 1 (Default):
profile 192.168.0.1
static ip_address=192.168.0.250/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.11 192.168.0.12 192.168.0.1

# Static IP Configuration 2:
profile 192.168.1.1
static ip_address=192.168.1.250/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12 192.168.1.1
```

The strange thing is that this seems to work atleast when the server is first turned on, however if I need to reboot the router when it reboots the server gets an IP address which is not the static IP configured as above.  I'm unsure how to go about troubleshooting this, any advice or points in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have `dhcpcd` installed (I use `dhclient`) but reading the [dhcpcd.conf man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5.en.html) for Debian 10, it seems that when you use `arping` to select a static IP profile, then the profile name should not be an IP address but the hardware address (i.e. MAC address) of the thing that will respond to the ARP ping in each case.

In the [corresponding man page for Debian Stretch](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5.en.html), the example on the use of `arping` with `profile` is unclear: it looks like a patching error has deleted some lines from the example. In Debian 10 the error seems to have been fixed.

When you reboot the router, it apparently takes a while after enabling links on its interfaces before it's capable of actually answering to ARP requests. The Debian Stretch system probably has a faster processor than an average router, so it will do its arpings as soon as it sees a link come up, and the arpings will fail as the router is still in the middle of its start-up process.

The `dhcpcd` will then fall back to regular DHCP, which has longer timeouts and so it will eventually get a DHCP response from a router and use it. If you don't want that, the best you can do is probably to use the `fallback` keyword to pick the most common case and hope it's the correct choice.

If you can configure the routers, you could also probably configure each router to recognize the server's MAC address and always give it the desired IP address using regular DHCP. That would be the usual way to get static IPs while using DHCP, but I assume you cannot do that for some reason.

So you would want something like this:

```
interface enp30s0
# the most often used router first, to make things happen more quickly
arping 192.168.1.1 192.168.0.1

# Second router 192.168.1.1 has MAC address 11:22:33:44:55:66 in this example
# ISP router 192.168.0.1 has MAC address 22:33:44:55:66:77 in this example

# if arping fails, the next step would normally be to use the regular DHCP. 
# Assume we're on the second router in that case instead, since it's the most common case
fallback 11:22:33:44:55:66

# Static IP Configuration for the second router:
profile 11:22:33:44:55:66
static ip_address=192.168.1.250/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.11 192.168.1.12 192.168.1.1

# Static IP configuration for the ISP router:
profile 22:33:44:55:66:77
static ip_address=192.168.0.250/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.11 192.168.0.12 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Oh that is interesting, I will make the amendments and report back when I can, thank you for your help!

Comment: I made those amendments, but with them the server gets a DHCP everytime and the static IP address is never assigned, I reverted back the changes and issued the commands `dhcpcd -k` and `dhcpcd` and I got back my static address.  I guess I need to figure out how to increase the timeout somehow as it's mentioned on the man page, but it's not in the config file will add it and see if anything changes.